# How do you code an HTML5 banner ad to the AIB standards?

Tags: html, banner

http://www.iab.net/html5?tid=2426832

Flash banner ads have to die at some point. HTML5 banner ads will win. But the question is: how? The IAB published some stuff, but it seems ineffective. Does anybody have actual experience in this area who is willing to share?

Answer (score 0):

Flash banners are amazing and a LOT easy to create, process and function on webpages and personal computers/laptops. While, HTML5 was created to function with iOS devices, the problem is Steve Job said that Adobe Flash content is not allowed to be viewed on the iOS devices because those contents pose a security risk **which is not true, never heard of such threats to occur, Adobe approves of this** - Although the actual reason why **Apple Company** stopped Flash to operate on their devices was entirely based on the idea that their profits will drop as soon as flash begins to function on iPhone, i Pad devices. And also, I've tried HTML5 content made some banners, the size of the content is very high compared to Adobe Flash content and their are problems with making the content properly function on some webpages. So HTML5 is a pain in the neck, while flash is very easy and preferable.